# I asked for the wrong thing and so made the answers to my question uncomplete. How should I correct this?

Tags: discussion, editing, asking-questions

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106269/how-to-put-something-in-footer-depending-on-page-number-context-plain-tex) I got two great answers on how to do what I asked for (putting the page number in the footer at the first page of each signature in a book). But --- as some of you probably understand --- it's of course the number of the **signature** that should go there to make it easier to order the signatures and bind them right.

This procedure is often done when printing books.

The answers to my question would be much more useful to any book designer if they instead answered the intended question: How do I put the **signature number** at the bottom of the first page of each signature?

Should I leave the question as is, and post a new question? Should I edit the question and notice the answerers? Offer a bounty?

Thankful for thought on best practices!

Comment: D@mn I suspected that and nearly answered the question I thought you might mean, but decided to answer the question you asked:-)

Comment: In general I'd agree with Alan that a new question makes sense but here the main question in the title (make the footer depend on the page number) still applies, and almost all of the calculation in the answer is the same, just print out a different number, so I'd update the question in this case and just ping each answer with a comment

Answer (score 33):

I think that editing a question after you've received good answers to it is generally bad practice, especially if it would change the validity of the answers.  If what you need could be done with a minimal change, it might be possible to add a comment to each answer with an extra question.  This will notify the original answerers and let them update their answers.

So I think your intuition to pose a new question is the correct one in most cases that the change would be a substantial one.  When you ask the  new question, you can add a link to the previous question.